# Better for loading speed: large JSON file, or small CSV file that requires processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

For maximum load speed and page efficiency, is it better to have:

1. An 18MB JSON file, containing an array of dictionaries, that I can load and start using as a native JavaScript object (e.g. `var myname = jsonobj[1]['name']`).
2. A 4MB CSV file, that I need to read using the jquery.csv plugin, and then use lookups to refer to: `var nameidx = titles.getPos('name'); var myname = jsonobj[1][nameidx]`).

I'm not really expecting anyone to give me a definitive answer, but a general suspicion would be very useful. Or tips for how to measure  - perhaps I can check the trade-off between load speed and efficiency using Developer Tools.

My suspicion is that any extra efficiency from using a native JavaScript object in (1) will be outweighed by the much smaller size of the CSV file, but I would like to know if others think the same.

Comment: Benchmark, benchmark, benchmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your situation? Are you writing some intranet site where you know what browser users are using and have something like a reasonable expectation of bandwidth, or is this a public-facing site?

If you have control of what browsers people use, for example because they're your employees, consider taking advantage of client-side caching. If you're trying to convince people to use this data you should probably consider breaking the data up into chunks and serving it via XHR.

If you really need to serve it all at once then:

1. Use gzip
2. Are you doing heavy processing of the data on the client side? How many of the items are you actually likely to go through? If you're only likely to access fewer than 1,000 of them in any given session then I would *imagine* that the 14MB savings would be worth it. If on the other hand you're comparing all kinds of things against each other all the time (because you're doing some sort of visualization or... anything) then I imagine that the JSON would pay off.

In other words: it depends. Benchmark it.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful answer. It's a public-facing site where people may use desktop or mobile browsers. Yes, I will be using all the data, and I don't need to do heavy processing, but I will need to refer to each item in each object. (It's a visualisation.) Any suggestions for good benchmarking tools?

Comment: If the visualization is running for long enough and modifying the data regularly then I would imagine that processing time will eventually dominate: it doesn't matter how fast the page loads if once it does the animation is stuttery. But if it's static (like a dynamically generated image or plot) then the page load time is what you care about. If it's an animation I'd say write it with the csv technique and see if it works "well enough" on your phone. Basically, just test it functionally in the most limited conditions you can create, or are willing to demand of your users.

Comment: Which is to say that, no, I don't know about any visualization-testing frameworks. I don't know the space at all though, so they could definitely exist. But visualizations themselves are usually used as tests for the underlying platform, so you're more writing the test then looking for one. I bet if you wrote both versions people would be very interested in your results.

Answer (score 5):

Did you considered delivering the json content using gzip - here is some benchmarks on gzip http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/05/entry_263.html

Comment: @Richard If the content is gzipped, the file size difference is probably negligible, try it, just create a gzipped version of the file using `gzip`

Comment: @JuanMendes you are right - 0.8MB versus 1MB! So it hardly matters at all - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

4MB vs 18MB? Where problem? Json is just standard format now, csv is maybe same good and ok if you using it. My opinion.

Answer (score 0):

14Mb of data are a HUGE difference, but I will try first to serve both the content with `GZIP/Deflate` server side compression and, thus, make a comparison of these requests (probably the CSV request will be again better in content length)

Then, I would also try to create some data manipulation tests on [`jsperf`](http://jsperf.com) both with CSV and JSON data with a real test case/common usage

Answer (score 0):

That depends a lot on the bandwidth of the connection to the user.

Unless this is only going to be used by people who have a super fast connection to the server, I would say that the best option would be an even smaller file that only contains the actual information that you need to display right away, and then load more data as needed.